# Redirect with htaccess from path based to query based URL but exclude robots

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am struggling with `.htaccess` again, I just will never get it. My plan is to change the URL

```
http://example.com/page/subpage
```

to

```
http://example.com/page?popup=subpage
```

This should be done with the `.htaccess`. On top of that I need the old URL be reachable for the Twitter and Facebook crawlers. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: So the old URL is `http://example.com/page/subpage`? "Except robots"?! Please include the code you are "struggling" with.

Comment: The idea is, that I have the single subpages, so that Facebook can scrape all it's meta data. But the user should be able to see the "subpages" directly as a popup within the archive page.

So the old URL is `http://example.com/page/subpage` and it should be redirected to `http://example.com/page?popup=subpage`

I only tried different stuff in the htaccess, nothing worked so far. I am really bad with regular expressions. The last thing I tried was `RewriteRule ^page\/([^\/]+)\/? /page?subpage=$1 [L]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood, but... this seems like a strange requirement?

> ```
> RewriteRule ^page\/([^\/]+)\/? /page?subpage=$1 [L]
> ```

Providing this is near the top of your root `.htaccess` file then this kind of does what you are asking, except this is an *internal rewrite*, not an *external redirect* as you request in the question. This is also unconditional, so it would "redirect" everyone, including bots (ie. Facebook). (The regex also contains unnecessary escapes, but that just affects readability. The slash carries no special meaning in mod_rewrite regex, since it is not used as a delimiter.)

To make this into a *redirect*, you need the `R` flag. And in order exclude the Facebook and Twitter bot(s) you'll need to add preceding condition(s) that check the user-agent. So, something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebook|Facebot)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^Twitterbot
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)$ /page?popup=$1 [R,L]
```

Note that the user-agent header can be faked, so anyone can pretend to be a bot if they want to. This also excludes the trailing slash on the URL (as in your example). If the trailing slash really is optional then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* back to `^page/([^/]+)/?$`. This is a temporary (302) redirect.

The `RewriteCond` directive only allows access when the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` field does *not* (`!` prefix) start with "facebook" or "Facebot".

To exclude additional bots you would need to identify these bots by user-agent and include additional `RewriteCond` directives.

Reference for user-agents:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/crawler
- https://dev.twitter.com/cards/getting-started#crawling

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, it still is not working. Can it be because of the other entries that wordpress is using? This is the whole htaccess now:

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^(facebook|Facebot)
RewriteRule ^episode/([^/]+)$ /episodes?episode=$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: This directive needs to go "near the top of your ... `.htaccess` file", before the existing WordPress directives. If you put it after the WP directives then it's not going to do anything (because WP rewrites all requests to `index.php`).

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not working. I put it completely up, directly under `RewriteEngine On`. I also checked it in a htaccess tester tool. It sais that the rule is not matched. Do we miss anything here? Htaccess is like rocket science to me...

Comment: "It sais that the rule is not matched." - ?! The above `RewritRule` will definitely match a `/page/subpage` request. What request URL are you using? I notice in the above comment that "episode" (no "s" maps to "episodes" (with an "s") - is that correct? Should `page` also be mapped across to the target URL, like `subpage` is?

Comment: I will post an actual URL, maybe there is some difference that I haven’t noticed. I want to change

`http://test.example.com/episode/staffel-1-folge-2-fototag/`

to 

`http://test.example.com/episodes?popup=staffel-1-folge-2-fototag`

The „s“ in episodes is important, because this is the archive page of all episodes. And there I want to show the popups.

Comment: Ah, you have a trailing slash on the request URL - this is not present on your example, so I removed it from the pattern in the code sample (but I noted: "If the trailing slash really is optional then change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ back to `^page/([^/]+)/?$`"). If the trailing slash is always present then remove the `?` before `$`. Also, I've just noticed that I had `?subpage=` in the `RewriteRule` _substitution_. That should obviously be `?popup=`. (Now corrected.) You have `?episode=` in the directive you posted above, which should presumably be `?popup=`?

Comment: It worked!! Thanks for your patience, you save my day!